# How to save an outlook appointment in users calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I am developing an asp.net web application which allows users to syn any Event from the gridView to there Outlook appointment using the following code:

```
private void generateOutlookAppointment(string subject, string location, string startDate, string endDate)
        {
            string body = "Test Data for Body.";


            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);

            oAppointment.Subject = subject;
            oAppointment.Body = body ;

            oAppointment.Location = location;
            oAppointment.Start = DateTime.Parse(startDate).AddHours(9);
            oAppointment.End = DateTime.Parse(endDate).AddHours(9);
            oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; 
            oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;
            oAppointment.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; 
            oAppointment.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;

            oAppointment.Save();
        }
```

Code works fine when I run locally in visual studio localhost, but fails on server.
Not sure logically would it be able to store an outlook appointment on client outlook since the code is running at server.

Please point me to right direction, even in case I need to use different approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code on your server cannot access Outlook on the client's machine.  What you need to do is create a VCS file, allow the client to download it, and if their machine is setup correctly Outlook will launch and create the appointment.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook, just like any other Office app, cannot be used in a service (such as IIS).
See [How to access client's outlook in ASP.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093200/how-to-access-clients-outlook-in-asp-net/1094257#1094257) for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I always did it as an email to the user.  A lot of sites online have the required data that needs to be sent to convert an email to a meeting request, here's an example.

http://sahannet.blogspot.com/2010/09/create-outlook-vcalendar-reminder-file.html